# Words with pronunciations more complex than spelling

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The word *mischievous* is [sometimes pronounced with a long e sound between the v and the last vowel](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-11640951) (mis-chee-vee-us), although this is controversial.

Is there a name for this type of word, where the pronunciation is made more complex than the spelling indicates?

Comment: What do you mean by "more complicated"? Would colonel -> kernel be an example?

Comment: That's the opposite idea, where the pronunciation is simpler than the spelling. I think this is quite common, e.g. silent letters, non rhotic pronunciations, words like 'Wednesday' etc.

Comment: I would suggest that "mischevious", while usually spelled as "mischievous", is actually a portmanteau of "mischievous" and "devious".

Answer (score 4):

The name for the type of error is *[misconstruction](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misconstruction)*:

> **misconstruction** 2. *Grammar* A faulty construction, especially of a sentence or clause.

Although the definition refers specifically to sentences or clauses, it can be used for single words as well.

**edit**

From NOAD, for those who think "mischievious" is a variant:

> *usage*: **Mischievous** is a three-syllable word. Take care not to use this incorrect four-syllable pronunciation: |misˈCHēvēəs|.

Comment: I'm not asking about errors, I'm asking about pronunciations that are shared, understood and used deliberately. If you follow my link you will see that its suggested that young people in Britain often use the _mis-chee-vee-us_ pronunciation. Your link doesn't say that _misconstruction_ is used to describe pronunciations.

Comment: @bdsl: Here's [a link that does](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mischevious).

Comment: @Robusto: is "mischevious" really an error? So many people say it. I'm not sure I've ever heard a native local speaker say "mischievous".

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: [Taps the link] I don't hear the word used much at all, but when I do it's pronounced *mischievous*. And, yes, I think it really is an error. None of my dictionaries lists *mischevious*, btw. And I'm updating my answer with a usage note from NOAD.

Comment: oxforddictionaries.com agrees with you: "[mischievous] should not be pronounced with four syllables...". But I still don't think this shows that its an error. People may be deliberately doing something different to what the dictionary says. I don't think most people care much about how dictionaries say words should be pronounced, they follow pronunciations that they hear other people use and that they find will be understood without complaint by their listeners.

Comment: @bdsl: True, and if enough of them use the "wrong" pronunciation, then dictionaries start listing that as well. So far that hasn't happened, ergo it's still considered "wrong" ...

Comment: [Merriam-Webster lists it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mischievous) as long-standing, but "non-standard".

Comment: Is the four-syllable form really a misconstruction, or is "mischevious" really a portmanteau of "mischievous" and "devious"?

Comment: @supercat: Interesting theory, but I doubt it. It's heard too often to be an intentional portmanteau. Most people aren't that clever.

Comment: @Robusto: It wouldn't take very many people being clever--just one person coining it, and others thinking it was cute, perhaps without quite realizing why.  I've used the word jokingly as an emphatic from time to time without thinking about why it's emphatic; it's actually only today that I realized its rhyme with "devious" and, upon further consideration, realized that in most places where the "mischevious" pronunciation is used, there is an element of deviousness rather than mere mischief.

Comment: @supercat: I thought about it, and then I thought: why? Best-case scenario for your theory: maybe one or two "thought leaders" intended a portmanteau when pronouncing it that way, and the rest just thought that was the correct pronunciation. Occam's Razor and all that.

Comment: @Robusto: Even before realizing the connection, hearing that someone was "three-syllable mischievous" would conjure up images of mindless rowdiness, while "four-syllable mischevious" would conjure up images of someone who was scheming a way to get away with something.  Given the difference in meaning, it would seem extremely plausible that someone coined "mischevious" as a portmanteau, but it wasn't regarded as a new word.  Too bad there's no way to search radio and television archives based on pronunciation, since that could probably lend some clues.

Comment: @Robusto: Perhaps an intentional portmanteau, or perhaps accidental, but I don't think that pronunciation would be so popular if it didn't contain part of a word related to a particular kind of mischief.

Comment: @Robusto: Do you know if there's a way to search literature for the word `"mischevious"`, *in quotes or italics*?  An ngrams search shows that the word has appeared occasionally, nearly forever, but it's likely many occurrences were typographical errors or misspellings.  On the other hand, if e.g. a character in a book, script, or silent movie intertitle were to say e.g. "He's got a *mischevious* look in his eyes", with the italic, that would suggest a deliberate usage.  Silent comedies often used wordplay in their title cards, so it's not hard to imagine "mischevious" having been used in one.