# Are there any English words pronounced with sounds/syllables that aren't part of the spelling?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

There are many English words with silent letters, words like *gnome* or *island* that are spelt with consonants that aren't pronounced, but are there any words that work the other way round, with a pronunciation that includes extra sounds or syllables that are not in the spelling?

I can't think of any real examples, hence this question, but a made-up example would be if *gnome* were spelt *nome* but pronounced with a *g* at the start. Or if people started pronouncing *offer* as "ofter" as a sort of weird parallel to *after*.

Note: I don't mean words like *rough*, where the *f* sound is spelt *gh*, because in those cases the spelling does still include letters (however seemingly illogical) for each of the sounds.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96502/discussion-on-question-by-nnnnnn-are-there-any-english-words-pronounced-with-sou).

Comment: By allowing answers to include extra syllables and vowels  that are not represented by letters , you're opening a Pandora box. The question's become too broad

Comment: Syllables aren't in the spelling!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The point of the question was essentially are there *any* words with the "opposite" of silent letters, so it was kind of a yes/no question but with examples to prove the "yes". So broad, but not *too* broad I think. Many of the examples given seem obvious now in hindsight, but yesterday when I asked the question I felt there were such words but had a mental blank and couldn't think of any at all, so this has been helpful for me, and I hope might be helpful or at least interesting to others.

Comment: This is similar to my (only) question on this site, but it's got some great answer's that my question didn't get. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37629/words-with-pronunciations-more-complex-than-spelling

Comment: Not sure it really counts, but the word _vegetable(s)_ is occasionally heard pronounced as _vegestable(s)_ for humorous effect – that’s an extra s that’s not there in the spelling.

Comment: Knock yourself out with these answers posted on a locked question: [What words are commonly mispronounced by literate people who read them before they heard them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-th)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Probably "yes", but it depends on what you mean. There isn't actually a clear way to identify which sounds in a word correspond to which letters: for example, *rough,* which you say has letters for "each of the sounds", could be analyzed as *r-* + *-ou-* + *-gh* or as *r-* + *-o-* + *ugh.* When similar issues arise with other words, it makes it pretty subjective to decide whether the word has consonant sounds that "aren't part of the spelling" or that just have an complex relationship to the spelling.

Some words that could be considered to meet your criteria:

#### Consonants

- Any word with an epenthetic voiceless plosive between a nasal and a following consonant. For many speakers, a productive process causes a sound like /t/, /p/ or /k/ to be inserted after the sounds /n/, /m/ or /ŋ/ respectively in various environments. In most words, the epenthetic plosive is not written, so you could say that there is a /p/ in the pronunciation but not the spelling of *warmth, dreamt, hamster, seamstress,* a /t/ in the pronunciation but not the spelling of *sense, glance,* a /k/ in the pronunciation but not the spelling of *strength, angst.*
- In *eighth* and in one pronunciation of *threshold,* a digraph that usually represents a single sound corresponds instead to two sounds: /tθ/ and /ʃh/ respectively. You could say that the /t/ in *eighth* or the /h/ in that pronunciation of *threshold* isn't part of the spelling.

  Something similar applies for speakers who use the pronunciation [/haıtθ/](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169553/77227) instead of /haıt/: whether it's spelled *height* or *[heighth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heighth),* it seems like one of the two sounds at the end is not explicitly represented in the spelling.
- In some accents of British English, the vowels found in words like *saw* and *draw* is regularly followed by epenthetic /r/ before another vowel. This means that the words *sawing* and *drawing* are pronounced with an /r/ that "isn't part of the spelling".

#### Vowels or syllables

- Many words with syllabic resonants, or sequences of a schwa followed by a resonant, have no particular letter that marks the syllabicity. Words ending in *-thm* or *-sm* are the most obvious example. Other examples are more dialect dependent, but words like *hour* are disyllabic for some speakers.

Comment: Good answer. Hamster, etc., exhibit exactly the sort of thing I had in mind. Drawing is an interesting one that also fits my admittedly vague and subjective criteria.

Comment: I like the mention of saw and draw in BrE. It's a peculiar little detail that I like about BrE.

Comment: Regarding the edit, I'm used to hearing and saying eighteen with just the one t sound, but I can see why some people might say it the way you described.

Comment: The /t/ sound in *sense* and *glance* was very hard for me to sense (pun intended) until I started thinking about the difference between *glans* and *glance* (the "ce" and "s" providing a supposedly identical sound).

Comment: I remember that some time in the '90s, an /r/ appeared in "Diana and Charles" (and other combinations of words, but this is a useful one to remember).

Comment: You say: eighteen is usually pronounced like "eight teen" but actually it is normally pronounced "ay-teen" unless the speaker is trying VERY hard to make it clear, eg over a radio.

Comment: @Jos Similarly "Law and Order" became "Laura Norder".  
sumelic: for no good reason, "threshold" really cheered me up - what a cracking example :)

Answer (score 76):

**Lieutenant** in British English is pronounced with an f: /lɛfˈtɛnənt/.

Comment: While we're on the topic of army ranks, would you like to mention *colonel*? :)

Comment: @Tanner not quite an answer to this question, for while it has weird vowels and a silent "l" there's no extra consonant.

Comment: I always thought of the /f/ coming from the "u" letter, which would have denoted a /v/ sound in earlier spelling systems.

Comment: @Talies Could be. Wikipedia notes there was a rare spelling in French of "luef". The letter F is older than U however.

Comment: *Facepalm* - I always, for no real reason, assumed that in the UK/British military, `Leftenant` was a different rank than `Lieutenant`. ....Either in the a different branch (e.g. Army vs Navy), or a difference for Commissioned/Non-Commissioned ranks, or ...something. Learned something new today :O

Comment: Similarly the often-heard English pronunciation of _constable_ as _counstable_ – I cant think of any other cases where orthographic <o> represents diphthongal /aʊ/.

Comment: @curiousdanii: *colonel* has an /r/ in American English; it's a homophone of *kernel*.

Comment: The internet tells me that dachshund does contain letters mapping to all of the sounds in "doxen", but I don't believe it...

Comment: @user3067860 "d" maps to "d", "a" maps to "o", "chs" maps to "ks" which maps to "x", the creator of that phonetic pronunciation probably intended a silent "h", "u" maps to "e", "nd" maps to "n", where, again, the creator probably treated the ending "d" as silent. I usually pronounce this word (Midwest American English) closer to "doxhend", which is closer to the original German pronunciation.

Comment: @PeterShor Wiktionary says neither has a full r consonant. It has this for US, using an r colored vowel: ˈkɝnəl. But maybe people differ in their analysis of it.

Comment: @PeterShor 'Colonel' and 'kernel' have distinct 'r' sounds in my Scottish accent, much more pronounced that wikipedia apparently suggests, though they still aren't homophones, more like 'curr-n'l' and 'kErnel'.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet can you explain in a different way what you mean by 'constable' sounding like 'counstable'? To me 'coun' would be pronounced pretty close to 'cow' with an 'n' added and I can't relate that to a pronunciation I've ever heard of 'constable'. The closest would be 'cunstable'.

Comment: @Spagirl That’s exactly what I mean, like _count_ with an s before the t. I don’t recall hearing it in Scottish English (I’m going mainly by tv shows here), but it’s a common pronunciation in English detective shows.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not to put you on the spot, but can you name one of the shows? If I can come up with a specific actor I might be able to work out how they say it, because despite having English parents and living there for 11 years, I can't currently map your description to something I recognise. Are you drawing a distinction between the sounds you'd get from 'counst' and 'cunst'?

Comment: @Spagirl Yes, I’d call _cunstable_ /ˈkʌnstəbəl/ more or less the standard (I hear it more frequently than /ˈkɒnstəbəl/, at any rate), and _counstable_ definitely a variant. I can’t recall specific instances of it, it’s just something I’ve always noticed when I do hear it. I’m almost, but not entirely, certain John Barnaby (Neil Dudgeon) in _Midsomer Murders_ says it that way.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet i can't look up recordings of him right now, but I'll try to remember to later. Thanks for humouring my curiosity.

Comment: @Spagirl Incidentally, searching Google Books for _counstable_ (as such) does give me a few hundred results, spanning from the 1600s all the way up until the 21st century, which would seem to support it as an actual variant pronunciation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'll maybe look at some of those. To be clear, I wasn't casting aspersions as to veracity, bust trying to understand just what the sounds were in this pronunciation.

Comment: @curiousdannii _colonel_ has an _r_ sound in all dialects I am aware of. And yet is always spelled without an _r_. It's the most obvious example of such a word I can think of since it's dialect independent and always contains a sound that could never be inferred from the spelling.

Comment: @terdon Definitely doesn't in my own non-rhotic AusEng. I assume it's similar for other non-rhotic accents.

Comment: @curiousdannii really? I stand corrected, thanks. I assume it's still a homophone of _kernel_ though, right? So there's at least a _e_ that isn't in the spelling?

Comment: @terdon Right, they're homophones. Same vowel as in 'fur'. And 'fir'. ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii It has an /r/, just not an [r]. So you’re correct that it doesn’t have an r _sound_, but it does have an r _phoneme_ (unless you choose to completely separate non-rhotic dialects phonemically from rhotic ones and create separate phonemes for r-coloured vowels, that is; but that’s rather uneconomic in most cases).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I often hear an extra "t" in the pronunciation of "constable", between the "n" and the "s", but I think it's a deliberate mutation in order to  denigrate our excellent Police officers. :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’ve watched a lot of videos snippets now and never catch him saying ‘constable’... his pronunciation shall remain forever a mystery to me.

Comment: @Spagirl I think I just happened upon one on telly which I think is a match (though I sort of just caught it after it was said, so I could be mistaken). _Endeavour_, S3E3 (“Prey”), somewhere around the 1:05:00 mark. WPC Trewlove has just briefed the team about a vial of musk having been stolen from a lab, and CS Bright says, “That’s first-rate work, counstable”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’ll look that out next time I’m on YouTube

Answer (score 32):

"Colonel", which is pronounced identically to "kernel", as though the "lo" in the middle was somehow an "r".

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to count cases where an illogical consonant is used, so this doesn't quite fit the OP's requirements.

Comment: Yes, by my admittedly subjective criteria this isn't the sort of thing I had in mind, though it is at least in an adjacent neighbourhood.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Per the inimitable Jon Purdy: [It'd be better to say that though it was originally spelt *coronel* and retains that pronunciation, the spelling was *artificially* changed during 16th-century spelling reform.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/whats-the-deal-with-colonel#comment16450_9831) In other words, reformists changed the orthography but that isn't going to make people suddenly forget how they've long been saying it.

Comment: N.B. that's U.S. English only.

Answer (score 17):

Do you count words borrowed from another language that pronounces consonants differently? If so, I'd nominate **pizza**, which in American English is pronounced with a **T** (peet'-za).

There's also the common pronunciation of "sandwich" as "sa**m**wich", but that's a replacement, not an insertion.

Comment: In the case of *pizza*, the pronunciation is just recognizing that it's an Italian word rather than an English word.

Comment: Thus the preface about whether or not you count borrowed words. Note, though, that _piazza_ is often pronounced _without_ the T, at least on this side of the Atlantic.

Comment: Borrowed words that have retained their foreign spelling and (perhaps approximate) pronunciation weren't what I was thinking of originally, but taken as what is now a standard English word I think pizza qualifies, especially given that the majority of other English words with a double z don't have that same t sound.

Comment: I know of at least one language (Hebrew) where the 'tz' sound is considered a single distinct consonant sound with its own letter.

Comment: And in German, the letter z's sound _is_ tz.

Comment: @jeffB Which is "this side of the Atlantic"? I guess you're on the wrong side, because over here, *piazza* is pronounced like it's Italian, and not at all like *plaza,* even though the two words are very closely related.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well, I'm not on the _right_ side, at least if you're looking down with north to the top. Or if you're watching the news.

Answer (score 16):

Consonants that are pronounced but unmarked in spelling are relatively uncommon. There are a finite number of historical sound changes, and most of them involve either transforming one sound into another (assimilation; dissimilation) or removing the sound from a word (elision or deletion). (["Historical Sound Changes," Nativlang.com](http://www.nativlang.com/linguistics/historical-sound-changes.php))

Adding a sound to a word is known as **epenthesis**. In many cases, consonants added as a result of *epenthesis* result from dialect features like rhoticity ([ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/rhoticity-speech-4065992)). While we often think of "r" being dropped in dialects (Boston: "Pahk the cah in Hahvahd Yahd"), sometimes they are added. In the American South, I grew up with "**sherbert**" for the word "**sherbet**"; the pronunciation is common enough for [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/sherbet-vs-sherbert) to describe it as a variant.

Non-dialect epenthesis resulting in an un-spelled but pronounced consonant is less common, since our spelling system was standardized relatively recently. So sounds like the "p" in *pumpkin* (historically also *pumkin* according to the OED) are marked in the spelling.

Here are a few other examples that show a range of consonant insertions:

- "warsh" for *wash* (placed in the Mid-US in this [SE question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160117/where-does-the-intrusive-r-come-from-in-warsh))
- "hain't" for *ain't* ([Appalachian English](http://appalachianmagazine.com/2018/11/09/appalachian-english-why-we-say-warsh-rag-low-tar/))
- "drawring" for *drawing* (British English, passim)
- "hampster" for *hamster* (common; [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hamster) notes the */p/* option)
- "warmpth" for *warmth* (common; again, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warmth) notes the optional */p/*)

Comment: What would it mean for something to be "non-dialect"? I guess you mean "in Standard English", but even then, American English and British English have quite different "standard" forms. I'm also surprised to see the assertion that spelling was standardized "relatively recently", given the vast number of spellings that demonstrate abandoned pronunciations. For that matter, there are spellings that have ended up standardised in ways that _never_ matched pronunciation, like "debt".

Comment: 1. The usage would have to be common across multiple large dialect areas, such that the usage no longer characterizes a single dialect group. That development takes time. 2. Pre-caffeine brain; "relatively recently" is 200-300 years ago, as distinguished from 1000+ years of English where spelling was not standardized. Yes, lots of standardized spellings represent abandoned pronunciations, but most pronunciation changes are transformations or deletions of sounds or *epenthesis* of vowels.

Comment: Besides dropping r’s in Boston, New Englanders also add an r to words ending in a vowel followed by a word beginning with one. The late senator Edward Kennedy’s speeches are remarkable for this.  “Asia, Africa, and Latin America” becomes Asier, Afriker, and Latin America.”

Answer (score 11):

[Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mischievous) includes "mis-ˈchē-vē-əs" as a nonstandard pronunciation of **mischievous**, and has no entry for "mischievious".

Comment: Where is the added sound? Are you talking about the letter v being pronounced 'vee' ?

Comment: It sounds like the added sound is the "ē" after the "v".  It matches an imaginary spelling ending in "ious" instead of "ous."  And now I can't remember how I pronounce or spell it -- all 4 options look/sound right to me!

Comment: Excellent example! _Mischievious_ is indeed a very common pronunciation of _mischievous_.

Comment: Much to my chagrin, I've just discovered that "mischievious" is not a new thing.  Google books has examples from the 17th, 18th, 19th and 20th centuries.  However they are nowhere near as numerous as "mischievous", and I've only found "mischievous" in the 16th century.

Answer (score 7):

People sometimes add an L sound to the word 'saw' when it's followed by a word that begins with a vowel, e.g., "I sawl it."  This is common in south New Jersey.

Comment: That's interesting, I've never heard that.

Comment: Similarly in Philadelphia (which is very close to NJ, for our non-US-inhabitants); I've heard "drawl" instead of "draw". In addition, the digraph "st" is often pronounced "sht", as in "crossing the shtreet".

Comment: A similar and well-known feature of the Bristol (UK) accent is to put an L onto any word ending witrh a vowel. The story goes that the town was originally Bristow but the spelling changed to suit the way the inhabitants pronounce it.

Comment: I've observed this with the word "bra".

Comment: And a lot of people I've known pronounce "drawing" as "drawling."

Comment: @Dancrumb Specifically the (initial?) cluster /str/, or any /st/? Would anyone ever tell someone to _shtop shtaring at me from across the shtreet_, for example?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Obviously, I can't answer for Dancrumb, but I've read that although retraction of /s/ to [ʃ] in English is thought to have started in *str-* clusters, it has been observed in other clusters (see the quote in my [post on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/30133/5581))

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet good question. I'm not sure if it occurs when the following sound is a vowel <google google google>, looks like it might be limited to `str`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_English

Answer (score 5):

[Segue](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/segue) comes to mind, pronounced /ˈseɡ.weɪ/.

Comment: A 'w' is already a semi-vowel however.

Comment: But surely the /w/ is "part of the spelling" here—it's the letter "u".

Comment: I find it deliciously ironic that when finally there is an instance of a word in English actually being spelt in a way that almost exactly matches its pronunciation letter by letter (allowing for <e> to represent /eɪ/), it gets offered up on a list of words with unintuitive spellings!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Every word is spelled intuitively for an appropriate definition of intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

In UK people sometimes add an '**h**' in front of words beginning with a vowel.

They are people who habitually "drop their aitches" at the start of a word, so they might say

> I 'appen to 'ave five 'undred quid

and because, to them, that is the perfectly normal way to speak, they sometimes add an unnecessay '**h**' to words that don't need one, as a mockery of "lardy-dardy" people who "talk posh". So they might say

> Have you got **h**any **h**apples?

and pronounce the first '**H**' when they normally would not. I have even seen it in writing, such as this notice on a door

> Please knock **h**as the bell will frite the parot.

although in this case the spelling mistakes show a lack of education, not mockery, and the message was written in the same way it would be spoken.

Comment: From *My Fair Lady*: "In 'ertford, 'ereford and 'ampshire, 'urricanes 'ardly hever 'appen." But I've never 'eard - ahem, heard - anyone speak like this in real life; perhaps it is dying out.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime it's true, these days I 'ardly hever 'ear that, but I saw the notice not long ago. People do still drop their aitches, and I think many of them don't really know if there is supposed to be an aitch there or not, so when they try to talk politely, say in front of royalty, they add a haitch where there ain't one.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/348795/21009

Comment: Arguably, those speakers merely change the h rather than dropping it: in Arabic, the ' is a consonant (hamza).

Answer (score 3):

**Nuclear**, which is often pronounced (wrongly!) with an extra syllable in the middle, more like ‘[nucular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucular)’…

Comment: That's not an extra syllable so much as a misplaced syllable. If that were the correct pronunciation it would count.

Answer (score 2):

The English city Bristol was originally called "Bristow" (in Middle English "Bridgestow", in Old English "Brycgstow"), but locals have/had a habit of adding an "l" to words ending with vowels, so it ended up being called "Bristol".  To be more precise, the "l" sound is more of an extremely rounded "aw", apparently, which sounds to most ears like an "l".

> Some inhabitants also speak an English dialect known colloquially as Bristolian (or even more informally as "Bristle" or "Brizzle"), in which an L sound is appended to words that end in an 'a' or 'o' (thus "area" becomes "areal", etc). This unique dialectal idiosyncrasy is known as the Bristol L (or terminal L).

https://www.bristol.org.uk/about/dialect/

In summary, that's a word that was pronounced with an extra letter that wasn't in its spelling, but now is, in order to spell it how it's pronounced.

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_of_Bristol#Dialect) entry is quite well written on this matter.

Comment: British place names are full of it - Leicester, Warwick, Gloucester... I know there's lots more too

Comment: There's also "Middlesbrough" whose football team "Middlesbrough FC" is usually referred to as "The Boro", reflecting the normal pronounciation which adds a syllable as if it were spelled "Middlesborough".

Answer (score 2):

A pretty significant fraction of Americans (including myself) often pronounce *both* as *bolth*.  I'm not a linguist, so I don't have a source to quote here, but it's common enough that I have had two random conversations on the topic.

The added *l* isn't quite as strong as if you actually tried to pronounce a word spelled *bolth*, but it is at least half of an *l* sound.

I am guessing that the OP is probably more interested in cases where the naive pronunciation is incorrect (i.e., where you *must* pronounce an extra consonant in order to be understood), in which case this example doesn't apply.  But I thought it was worth mentioning anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Edinburgh (/ˈɛdɪnbərə/)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edinburgh)

(Geographical names are somehow particular, but they are not excluded explicitly by the original question.)

Comment: Likewise the surname *Grosvenor* which is often used as a place name in England is usually pronounced 'grovesner' or 'grovener'. Heck, even Wednesday is generally pronounced whens-day. I'm not sure if these meet the original question though, since it asks for sounds not already present in the word.

Comment: Ed-in-bu-rgh  is the correct pronunciation of the city where I am writing this. Not a correct answer to the question.

Comment: @Mike And how exactly are you intending to pronounce _rgh_ as a syllable? I agree that this isn’t a very good example, but the schwa at the end of _Edinburgh_ (which **is** absolutely there) is a sound present in the pronunciation which isn’t reflected at all in the spelling.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  In this case,  _rgh_  is pronounced "ru" as in "rough" without the 'f'. Which is a _massive_ coincidence since 'burgh' is an alternative spelling of 'borough'...

Answer (score 1):

Do place names count?

There is a place called Cogenhoe in Northamptonshire (UK) which is pronounced /ˈkʊknoʊ/, at least by the locals.

Comment: Surely this is the opposite of the question that was asked?

Comment: Is it?  I thought that the K sound at the end of the first syllable (i.e. "Cook") was not represented by any letter in the word, which was what the OP was asking.  Perhaps I have misunderstood.

Comment: As far as British place names go, that looks to me like a fairly normal aural contraction/abreviation, so primarily there are letters there that are no longer (clearly) pronounced. In this case, "Cook" is how "Cog" is now pronounced, and "enhoe" has become "now", so I don't see any sounds with truly missing letters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a particular fan of "feud" and "fuel". Both have the same mysterious "y" sound with no obvious connection to the spelling.

Comment: Isn't the "y" sound directly connected to the "u" in each word? The name of the letter "U" is pronounced "yoo", not "oo" or "uh" or whatever. Your suggestion does remind me that "Fiona" is sometimes said with a "y" sound like fiord.

Comment: Maybe? U sometimes has a preceding Y sound (cute, puke, fume) and sometimes not (lute, puma, futon). I would think the E in feud would prevent the formation of the Y sound after the consonant (pneumatic, rheumatism, deuce).

Comment: In England, it is usual to pronounce *pneumatic* and *deuce* with a Y sound. The lack of this sound in the pronunciation of many American English speakers doesn't have to do with the spelling, it's because of the preceding consonant sounds /n/ and /d/. For these speakers, the sounds /n/ and /d/ prevent a Y sound from being used, regardless of the spelling (compare *nude, numeral* and *duke, duty, durable*). In both British and American English, the /r/ sound at the start of *rheumatism* prevents a Y sound from being used: the same applies to words like *rude, rule, rural, ruse.*

Comment: There are a few ways to put that into particular usage. Whew. That's a shew in for a rose of a different hue. Maybe we can raise a hew and cry. Adieu!

Comment: Leaving out this sound is known as yod-dropping, and is distinctive of American accents.

Answer (score 0):

The name "Ste**ph**en" [is pronounced](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/stephen) as "Ste**v**en", that is, "ph" is pronounced "v", which is unexpected.

Some notes:

- "ph" is normally pronounced "f", and both "v" and "f" are [labiodental fricatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labiodental_consonant#Labiodental_consonant_in_IPA), so this strange pronunciation doesn't come entirely out of the blue.
- The name can also be spelt "Steven" (e.g. Steven Tyler), thus matching the pronunciation.
- Admittedly, this is not exactly what you are asking for (it's like "colonel", where "lo" is pronounced as an "r"), but since you consider colonel "in an adjacent neighbourhood", you might be interested in "Stephen" as well.

Comment: Phial is still pronounced "vial", so I think you're right.  Wondering if the OP allows for when a word that has several spellings - like phial/vial - where one spelling satisfies the sound, but the other does not?

Comment: @Andrew _Phial_ is pronounced /ˈfaɪəl/, and _vial_ is pronounced /ˈvaɪəl/. One derives from the other, but there are two pronunciations, and each matches its own spelling – that’s why the spelling _vial_ exists at all.

Comment: Ok, so "phial" sounds like "file".  Perhaps, then, the "al" sound in "phial" has no corresponding spelling in "file"?  Similarly, "while" "wile" "bile" "tile" etc